# Select both date and time column if MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-oauth

Hi I'm trying select post where post date less than current date , AND post time less thank current time 
Unfortunately I put post date and post time on separate column ,
whenever I tried get post of current day and it time Passed

```
SELECT date_published,`twitter_post`,`twitter_pubstatus`,`time_published`
FROM `topics` WHERE date_published <= CURDATE() AND time_published < CURTIME()
```

this gives me wrong result of course as MYSQL filters Post with `time_published` less than current hour .
In short Ho can I apply condition to select post published in current date that it time earlier than current hour , AND SELECT other post which older than current date , 
I tried using `AS` statement to filter first result (where post are older than today) , and than join it with another result (whre posts are dated today and it time passed ). 
this is my  `topics` structure

```
twitter_post     user_id       date_published time_published
------------|-----------------|--------------|----------------
some post   |    6507763398   |  2016-04-22  |  22:00:21
other post  |    6507763398   |  2016-04-24  |  02:10:21
future post |    6507763398   |  2016-04-24  |  23:34:21
```

Comment: How about date_published  <= ' .date('Y-m-d').' and time_published < '.date('H:i:s') in the query. echo it up. lets c what you get.

Comment: First, store date and time as a single entity

Comment: @Strawberry that what I was thinking on but my script already have part for insearcing Date & Time  in separate column this will cause me rewrite insert script too . @ Plum I already outputted dates variable and all works fine but the issue Date and Time field are in different column

Comment: No harm rewriting bad scripts

Comment: I'll rewrite it , I separate date and time because PHP and Mysql date functions were confused me . I'll select @juergen-d as correct answer and thanks for hints .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE timestamp(date_published, time_published) <= NOW()
```

which is short and readable but cannot make use of indexes. To make it faster use

```
WHERE date_published < CURDATE()
  OR (date_published = CURDATE() AND time_published <= CURTIME())
```

Comment: Perfect I didn't know about `timestamp` function it will joint both date and time together and fixes my mistake .